# Why is it necessary to mark interrupt handler functions as static?

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

While reading "Linux kernel development" by Robert Love, I found at page 119:

> The interrupt handler is normally marked static because it is never called directly from another file.

For example:

```
static irqreturn_t intr_handler(int irq, void *dev)
```

But why it is so? I doubt this function is going to be called by the kernel and if we make it static, then how is the kernel going to call it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rhaphlp/v7r6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rhp.uml.diagrams.doc%2Ftopics%2Frhp_t_dm_using_interrupt_handlers.html), the way the function is used is by "registering" it with the kernel. That is, there's a function such as `InstallIntHdlr` which you call and pass a pointer to your handler. The kernel can then use that pointer to call the function itself.

My guess, though I'm not sure about this, is that `static` is used as a way of enforcing the proper usage of an interrupt handler. That is, since static functions can't be called from other files, it forces you to pass a pointer to it instead of calling it directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I got some hints